# How to go from ReaderEither<R, E, A>[] to ReaderEither<R, E[], A[]> in fp-ts?

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, fp-ts

In fp-ts, how do I go from `ReaderEither<R, E, A>[]` to `ReaderEither<R, E[], A[]>`? Essentially I want to convert an array of `ReaderEither` instances to a single `ReaderEither` instance.

I've tried searching for the answer, but haven't had much luck. I'm new to functional programming and fp-ts, so I'm still trying to wrap my head around all of the concepts and put them into practice. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I believe Traversable might be the key. I've found some examples of using it with Option and Either, but I'm having trouble getting it to work with ReaderEither.
https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/Traversable.ts.html

Comment: You can get a `ReaderEither<R, E, A[]>` from a `ReaderEither<R, E, A>[]` with [`sequenceT`](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/Apply.ts.html#sequencet), but I'm not sure how to accumulate the errors.

Comment: Are you sure you want a `ReaderEither<R, E[], A[]>`? This is the same as a `Reader<R, Either<E[], A[]>>`; do you want a `Reader<R, Either<E, A>[]>` instead?

Comment: Yes, I'm hoping to accumulate the results in one single `Either`, rather than having multiple `Either`'s

Comment: How do you want this to work? What if some of the `ReaderEither`s return a `Left` and some return a `Right`? Do you want the final `Either` to be dependent on the first `ReaderEither` (e.g. if the first `ReaderEither` returns a `Left`, return a `Left<E[]>` by accumulating the other `Left`s and discard the `Right`s)? And what if the `ReaderEither<R, E, A>[]` is empty?

Comment: Yes, that sounds like exactly what I'm trying to achieve; albeit, with one clarification: I'm hoping to return a `Left<E[]>` if any of the `ReaderEither`'s return a `Left`, not just if the first one returns a `Left`. So if the first `ReaderEither` returns a `Right`, but the second one returns a `Left`, I would still want to return a `Left<E[]>`. I would only want to return a `Right<A[]>` if all of the `ReaderEither`'s return a `Right`. Apologies if that is what you meant; I just want to be sure we're on the same page. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import * as A from 'fp-ts/Array'
import {left, right} from 'fp-ts/Either'
import * as R from 'fp-ts/Reader'
import {flow} from 'fp-ts/function'
import type {ReaderEither} from 'fp-ts/ReaderEither'

const sequenceRE: <R, E, A>(
  fs: ReaderEither<R, E, A>[]
) => ReaderEither<R, E[], A[]> = flow(
  // ReaderEither<R, E, A>[] -> Reader<R, Either<E, A>[]>
  A.sequence(R.reader),
  // Maps the reader: Reader<R, Either<E, A>[]> -> ReaderEither<R, E[], A[]>
  R.map(flow(
    // Either<E, A>[] -> Separated<E[], A[]>
    A.separate,
    // Separated<E[], A[]> -> Either<E[], A[]>
    s => s.left.length ? left(s.left) : right(s.right)
  ))
)

// Right [4, 6]
sequenceRE([r => right(r * 2), r => right(r * 3)])(2)
// Left ['foo', 'bar']
sequenceRE([r => right(r * 2), r => left('foo'), r => left('bar')])(2)
// Right []
sequenceRE([])(2)
```

The code does this:

- [`sequence`](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/Array.ts.html#sequence)s (from [`Traversable`](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/Traversable.ts.html#traversable-interface)) the `ReaderEither<R, E, A>[]` into `Reader<R, Either<E, A>[]>`
- [`separate`](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/Array.ts.html#separate)s (from [`Compactable`](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/Compactable.ts.html#compactable-interface)) the `Either<E, A>[]` from the reader into `{left: E[], right: A[]}`

  ```
  interface Separated<A, B> {
    readonly left: A
    readonly right: B
  }

  // For Array:
  declare const separate: <A, B>(fa: Either<A, B>[]) => Separated<A[], B[]>
  ```
- If there are any `Left`s, returns a `Left` with the `Left` values, and otherwise returns a `Right` with the `Right` values.

Comment: That worked beautifully. Thank you so much. I've been "spinning my tires" on this for days.